Michelson Parsing Error in Proposal Handler Integration
The propose entrypoint in the baseDAO contract can be used to dynamically add new proposal handlers (logic to be executed as the outcome of an accepted proposal). My goal is to add a handler that enables arbitrary contract interactions, allowing the contract to call any endpoint on any deployed contract. The validation of the call data is done by this Ligo logic, and it has this structure:
(pair %add_handler
  (pair (lambda %code
           (pair (pair (map %handler_storage string bytes) (bytes %packed_argument))
                 (pair %proposal_info
                    (address %from)
                    (nat %frozen_token)
                    (bytes %proposal_metadata)))
           (pair (pair (option %guardian address) (map %handler_storage string bytes))
                 (list %operations operation)))
        (lambda %handler_check (pair bytes (map string bytes)) unit))
  (string %name))

Here is a basic example that does pass the validation:
(Left (Left (Pair (Pair { 
    DROP ;
    NIL operation ;
    EMPTY_MAP string bytes ;
    NONE address ;
    PAIR ;
    PAIR }
  { DROP ; UNIT })
"sample")))

Into this above structure, I'd like to integrate this logic which is forwarding the contract call:
parameter (pair (address :destination) (pair (string :entrypoint) (bytes :parameter)));
storage unit;
code {
        CAR;
        UNPAIR;
        # Extract the destination contract address
        UNPAIR;
        
        # Convert the string to an entrypoint address
        CONTRACT (unit);
        IF_NONE { FAILWITH } { };
        
        # Pack the parameter bytes
        PUSH mutez 0;  # No tez is sent
        UNPAIR;
        PACK;
        
        # Call the target contract with the provided entrypoint and parameter
        TRANSFER_TOKENS;
        NIL operation;
        CONS;
        
        PAIR;
    };

This is how I'm attempting to put it all together:
(Left (Left (Pair 
    (Pair {
        UNPAIR ; SWAP ; UNPAIR ; SWAP ; DROP ; UNPAIR ;
        CAR; UNPAIR; UNPAIR;
        CONTRACT (unit %entrypoint);
        IF_NONE { FAILWITH } {};
        PUSH mutez 0; UNPAIR; PACK;
        TRANSFER_TOKENS;
        NIL operation; CONS;
        SWAP; PAIR;
        NONE address; PAIR 
    }
    { DROP; UNIT }
) "arbitrary_contract_interaction")))

and it gets rejected by the contract validator with: A FAILWITH instruction was reached {"int":"111"}
Any help will be valued.

your problem is because the signature of the Michelson that you provided is not the same as the one expected. This result in the unpack instruction to fail here (see that the None case fail with a unpacking_proposal_metadata_failed which is equivalent to 111 as you can see here).
I recommend you to use octez-client to verify that your Michelson is correct with octez-client -M mockup convert script <contract.tz> from michelson to michelson. If you use Visual studio code, you can try to use this extension nomadiclabs.vscode-michelson to have some color and it should tell you if you're Michelson is valid but it may be outdated for some things so I think you should always check with the octez-client command.
For example if I take your contract:
parameter (pair (address :destination) (pair (string :entrypoint) (bytes :parameter)));
storage unit;
code {
        CAR;
        UNPAIR;
        # Extract the destination contract address
        UNPAIR;
        
        # Convert the string to an entrypoint address
        CONTRACT (unit);
        IF_NONE { FAILWITH } { };
        
        # Pack the parameter bytes
        PUSH mutez 0;  # No tez is sent
        UNPAIR;
        PACK;
        
        # Call the target contract with the provided entrypoint and parameter
        TRANSFER_TOKENS;
        NIL operation;
        CONS;
        
        PAIR;
    };

Here is the return of the octez-client command:
Ill typed contract:
  01: { parameter (pair (address :destination) (pair (string :entrypoint) (bytes :parameter))) ;
  02:   storage unit ;
  03:   code { CAR
  04:          /* [ pair address string bytes ] */ ;
  05:          UNPAIR
  06:          /* [ address : pair string bytes ] */ ;
  07:          UNPAIR ;
  08:          CONTRACT unit ;
  09:          IF_NONE { FAILWITH } {} ;
  10:          PUSH mutez 0 ;
  11:          UNPAIR ;
  12:          PACK ;
  13:          TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
  14:          NIL operation ;
  15:          CONS ;
  16:          PAIR } }
At line 7 characters 9 to 15, wrong stack type for instruction UNPAIR:
  [ address : ... ].

For helping you to achieve what you want to do here is a contract that pass the command with the basic example that you provided
{ parameter unit ;
  storage unit ;
  code { DROP ;
         PUSH (or (or (pair (pair (lambda
                                     (pair (pair (map %handler_storage string bytes) (bytes %packed_argument))
                                           (pair %proposal_info
                                              (address %from)
                                              (nat %frozen_token)
                                              (bytes %proposal_metadata)))
                                     (pair (pair (option %guardian address) (map %handler_storage string bytes))
                                           (list %operations operation)))
                                  (lambda (pair bytes (map string bytes)) unit))
                            string)
                      unit)
                  unit)
              (Left (Left (Pair (Pair { DROP ;
                                        NIL operation ;
                                        EMPTY_MAP string bytes ;
                                        NONE address ;
                                        PAIR ;
                                        PAIR }
                                      { DROP ; UNIT })
                                "sample"))) ;
         DROP ;
         UNIT ;
         NIL operation ;
         PAIR } }

You'll just have to replace the basic example with the one that you want to test and if the contract pass the octez-client command your Michelson typechecks.
To help you to write Michelson, you should take a look at the documentation as complex Michelson can get really hard to read and easy to loose track of the stack.
With your Michelson alone, I don't fully understand how you want to implement this handler as when calling a contract you must respect its signatures.
I hope it helped :)

Thank you so much for engaging with this.
You mentioned the signature of the code being different from the schema, but I’m not understanding which piece of code you are referring to. The first block of code in my question does have the structure to pass the validation but just features a placeholder instead of the actual desired functionality (which is the Arbitrary Contract Execution). The reason I know it passes is because I was able to successfully submit a proposal of type add_handler to the contract https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/op3Zud8Czcs6ZMFH1sqcf9gsLRrfsnn4dmHwdhjKdjPVA7N49xo/28958578

I made that call using the web interface at https://tezos-homebase.com. It shows the code which was submitted here: https://tezos-homebase.io/explorer/dao/KT1VG3ynsnyxFGzw9mdBwYnyZAF8HZvqnNkw/proposal/ac934ebee27a33c529955b8e1662cf3dfeb131b446e03f46012348eb6ebc7407
this is the logic from the Homebase app that handles the code conversion into the bytes: https://gist.github.com/EightRice/96508e8625b207a0fbe0be3367eabe0d/edit

If relevant, this is the logic from the Homebase app that handles the code conversion into the bytes that the contract expects: https://gist.github.com/EightRice/96508e8625b207a0fbe0be3367eabe0d/edit
If I try your suggestion, it does fail with 111 (failed to decode proposal metadata), but I’m not sure if I should be trying to submit it in the same way I did with the code that worked (through the web app).

On a separate note, I did install tezos-client and tried the command octez-client -M mockup convert script <contract.tz> from michelson to michelson,
but I get: Error:  Unrecognized command.  I also get a warning that it can't connect to the local node, so maybe that's why.
However I installed the Michelson Kernel for Jupyter and can check that the code compiles. The weird thing is, if I test the code that works in the app (first block of code in my question), I get: ERROR: “execute” has to be explicitly defined (Left), but if I submit the same code through the app it works fine.

For the signature that does not match I'm talking about your attempt to put it all together. The last code I wrote in my answer is a contract that you can use to verify your answer using octez-client command. In this contract you can see your basic example appears, just replace it with your suggestion and use the command to verify that it works.

You said that if you tried my suggestion it fails. I don't understand because I didn't make any suggestion to solve your problem. I understand globally what you want to do, but, as I said, with this Michelson alone I can't make a proper suggestion to try to correct your Michelson. All I did was trying to expose some problem and propose a contract to help you verify your answer.

For the octez-client command that don't work, I don't really know why. I removed my octez-client and get the binary again from here https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/packages/28814523 and the command still works.
About the Michelson code, a simple example to show you that it's normal that it fails is this line PUSH mutez 0; UNPAIR; PACK;
First you push mutez 0 on the stack, so on the top of the stack there is a mutez. Then you try to UNPAIR the top of the stack which leads to a failure as the top of the stack is not a pair but a mutez as said before.
I don't really know about jupyter.

Turns out the command was failing because I wasn't running the node (or providing an external RPC).
My understanding is that I could use the piece of code you provided and make a call to the contract, which , even though it doesn't have the functionality, it passes the contract validation.  Trying to call it like this:  octez-client transfer 0 from tz1T5kk65F9oZw2z1YV4osfcrX7eD5KtLj3c to KT1VG3ynsnyxFGzw9mdBwYnyZAF8HZvqnNkw --arg "$(cat lambda.tz)" --burn-cap 0.1 (with your code in lambda.tz) and get simulation failed : https://gist.github.com/EightRice/0ee3cc57cbda04de05c219c053ba5cb8

My whole point with this contract is a contract to test your implementation, not to be passed in parameter of a contract (the command that you showed me would never work whatever the contract was).
See the contract like this:
{ parameter unit ;
  storage unit ;
  code { DROP ;
         PUSH (or (or (pair (pair (lambda
                                     (pair (pair (map %handler_storage string bytes) (bytes %packed_argument))
                                           (pair %proposal_info
                                              (address %from)
                                              (nat %frozen_token)
                                              (bytes %proposal_metadata)))
                                     (pair (pair (option %guardian address) (map %handler_storage string bytes))
                                           (list %operations operation)))
                                  (lambda (pair bytes (map string bytes)) unit))
                            string)
                      unit)
                  unit)
         <YOUR IMPLEMENTATION>
         DROP ;
         UNIT ;
         NIL operation ;
         PAIR } }

With <YOUR IMPLEMENTATION> being your solution, for example this one (it's yours):
(Left (Left (Pair 
    (Pair {
        UNPAIR ; SWAP ; UNPAIR ; SWAP ; DROP ; UNPAIR ;
        CAR; UNPAIR; UNPAIR;
        CONTRACT (unit %entrypoint);
        IF_NONE { FAILWITH } {};
        PUSH mutez 0; UNPAIR; PACK;
        TRANSFER_TOKENS;
        NIL operation; CONS;
        SWAP; PAIR;
        NONE address; PAIR 
    }
    { DROP; UNIT }
) "arbitrary_contract_interaction")))

Let's put the whole thing in a file contract.tz and call the command octez-client convert script contract.tz from michelson to michelson. If your solution is correct the command will work, if not it will not.
As I already said, this contract is not a solution, it was just me trying to provide you a way to test your solution without always making a real transfer.

Oh, thanks so much for clearing it up. I'm already using the actual deployed contract on ghostnet to test it. I can call it from the Homebase app (and it works with that code I showed), and now that got I my octez-client in functioning order I can call it as shown in my comment to your first answer. Having this simplified version you provided might be quicker, so thanks again!

@Arno: Please edit this answer into your original answer, as opposed to posting it as a second answer.
